# Textures won't show on OpenGL and Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

My textures won't show up on screen, just the colored square.
I collocated a condition and a cout sentence to let me know if the image is loaded on memory correctly. It does indeed, but texture won't show Why does this happen? Is there something I am missing?

Here is my code:

Header: Image.hpp

```
#ifndef IMAGEN_HPP_INCLUDED
#define IMAGEN_HPP_INCLUDED

// Especificacion de Image que nos ayudara a cargar y mostrar las imagenes
class Image
{
private:
   unsigned char* Data;
   int ancho;
    int alto;

 public:

// Constructor con parametros de Ancho y Alto que son de la imagen real y
// la direccion de la imagen
Image(int iw, int ih, const char* path)
{
    this->ancho = iw;
    this->alto = ih;

    CargarImagen(path);
}

// Funcion para cargar una imagen en memoria
int CargarImagen(const char* path)
{
    FILE *imagen = fopen(path, "r");
    int InfoTam = this->ancho * this->alto * 3;
    this->Data = (unsigned char*) malloc( InfoTam );

    if( imagen == NULL ){
        cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
        return 0; }
    else{
        cout<<"Imagen cargada"<<endl;
    }

    fread(this->Data, InfoTam, 1, imagen);

    fclose(imagen);
    return 1;
}

// Dibujar la imagen que esta en memoria
void Dibujar(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, this->ancho, this->alto, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Data);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(x, y);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(x + w, y);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(x + w, y + h);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(x, y + h);
    glEnd();
}
};

#endif
```

And this is main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h> //New
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

#include "image.hpp"

#define pi 3.1415962
int ancho=700, alto=700;
float cx, cy=70; //Posición inicial. Donde empieza a caer la basura
int xpos, ypos, caida=1; //Posicion del mouse

int puntaje=0;

//Declaracion de imagenes

Image* BotePapel = new 
Image(256,256,"/Users/luissegovia/Documents/Recycle.raw");
Image* Fondo = new 
Image(2048,2048,"/Users/luissegovia/Documents/Background.raw");


//Funcion de display
void CodeFun(){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   //Limpia Buffer
glPointSize(100);               //Tamaño del punto

//----------
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
BotePapel->Dibujar(3, 1, 10, 10);
//Fondo->Dibujar(0, 0, 700, 700);

//

glFlush();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
//Parametros de inicio de OpenGL

glutInit(&argc,argv); //Inicializar libreria Glut
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB); //Establece modo de 
visualizacion incial

glutInitWindowSize(ancho,alto); //Tamanio de ventana
glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);    //Posicion de la ventana
glutCreateWindow("Prototipo Juego 2D"); //Titulo de ventana
glClearColor(1,0.5,0.5,1);      //Color de fondo
gluOrtho2D(0,70,0,70);//Inicializacion del plano (1er cuadrante)

glutDisplayFunc(CodeFun);

glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Between the two code blocks, there is some non-English, I guess Spanish? Could you also translate that part, so that everyone on the site can understand? :-).

Comment: Ready! I just dais that the next code is the main.cpp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `glTexImage2D()` while not having created and bound any texture. While it is possible to use the default texture (`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)`), I wouldn't rely on it. So instead create one like this:

```
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
```

Then after that call `glTexImage2D()` and do what you already did.

However don't create the texture within `CargarImagen()`, as you don't want to create a new texture every frame.

So in relation to your current layout. Create the texture after `gluOrtho2D()` in `main()`. But keep `GLuint texture` as a global variable instead. Then everything should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, it appears that it worked! 
Regards! ^^